# What does NML tag convey?

Tags: stanford-nlp

Basic query:
Stanford parser version 4.0.0 uses NML tag. I think is a useful feature, but I do not fully understand it. So I would appreciate more information about it, e.g. its full form and the motivation for introducing it etc. Why does it treat "Income tax proposal" and "Fish tank water"
differently. Has parser learnt the use of NML tag correctly?

Following is optional, please read it if you think that I am making up a fictious tag!

Following information is just to establish that this a serious enquiry. My previous query about NML tag was rejected because my guess of meaning of NML tag mislead me and some how I gave a wrong example! I am sorry for that.

Please see:
https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/index.html?edu/stanford/nlp/trees/ModCollinsHeadFinder.html

Under the heading Changes:

QUOTE

Added NML head rules, which are the same as for NP.
NP head rule: NP and NML are treated almost identically (NP has precedence)
NAC head rule: NML comes after NN/NNS but after NNP/NNPS

UNQUOTE

I am getting NML tags in several sentences while running the Stanford parser version 4.0.0

Here is just one example:
Parsing [sent. 1 len. 7]: The income tax proposal was rejected .
(ROOT
(S
(NP (DT The)
(NML (NN income) (NN tax))
(NN proposal))
(VP (VBD was)
(VP (VBN rejected)))
(. .)))

Answer (score 1):

The `NML` label should be for a noun phrase that is modifying another word or phrase. So a good example would be `income tax proposal`.  `income tax` is an `NML` since it is serving as an adjective of proposal. It is describing the type of proposal.

Syntactically `income tax proposal` and `marriage proposal` share the same high level structure, a noun phrase describing another noun, so the point of NML is to note that the phrase `income tax` is a complete object and it is modifying the word `proposal` to generate the final `NP` of `income tax proposal`.

If the actual statistical parser is inconsistent, as in the case of `fish tank water`, that is more likely an error in the model itself, which is just something you have to accept.  Statistical parsers make lots of errors all the time.

Comment: If I said "pepperoni pineapple pizza", there would NOT be an NML, since "pepperoni pineapple" is not a noun phrase in that example. In this example both pepperoni and pineapple are modifying the word pizza.